How can I Filter the output of an Arrayformula
I have an array of data that I would like to re-format into a simple two-column list, while filtering out empty values.
I can create a list, but am unable to figure out how to filter the results within one formula, though I am able to sort the results.
Sample doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vcx6cVbES4X4-Dp1e40_mZpl5OSoE__u98BYp5uD9oU

Exact copy of How can I Filter the output of an arrayformula that has been answered. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Add Query Function
Removing the empty cells on the second column may be done by adding a Query function using the query: SELECT * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL.
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(A3:A14&"-"&B3:B14&"-"&C2:E2&" "&C3:E14)," ")),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL")

Output:









Apple-Red-SM
2


Apple-Red-MD
4


Apple-Red-LG
2


Apple-Green-SM
4


Apple-Green-MD
8


Apple-Green-LG
4


Pepper-Red-SM
2


Pepper-Red-MD
4


Pepper-Red-LG
2


Pepper-Green-SM
3


Pepper-Green-MD
6


Pepper-Green-LG
3



For Sorting:
To sort the output data based on value, you may add ORDER BY Col2 DESC or ORDER BY Col2 ASC to the query.
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(A3:A14&"-"&B3:B14&"-"&C2:E2&" "&C3:E14)," ")),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col2 ASC")

Output:









Apple-Red-SM
2


Apple-Red-LG
2


Pepper-Red-SM
2


Pepper-Red-LG
2


Pepper-Green-SM
3


Pepper-Green-LG
3


Apple-Red-MD
4


Apple-Green-SM
4


Apple-Green-LG
4


Pepper-Red-MD
4


Pepper-Green-MD
6


Apple-Green-MD
8



Reference:

QUERY


Please feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above.
